# How to use bokeh.layouts.GridSpec?

Tags: python, layout, bokeh

Looking at https://github.com/Maluuba/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/layouts.py I have a hard time figuring out how to actually show the result of the following code:

```
from bokeh.layouts import GridSpec
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

fig1 = figure() #... plotting..
fig2 = figure() #... plotting..
fig3 = figure() #... plotting..
fig4 = figure() #... plotting..
fig5 = figure() #... plotting..

gspec = GridSpec(2, 3)
gspec[0, 0:2] = fig1 
gspec[0, 2] = fig2 
gspec[1, 0] = fig3 
gspec[1, 1] = fig4 
gspec[1, 2] = fig5

show(gspec)  # where to use sizing_mode='stretch_both' ??
```

My goal is to plot fig1 over the span of 2 columns on row 1 and having figures 2-5 as the same size. All figures need to dynamically change size depending on window size. Anyone have an idea?

I´m using bokeh 1.4

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to span across columns using `bokeh.layouts.GridSpec` but here is a solution using `bokeh.layouts.layout` and specifying `plot_width` when creating the figures. I'm using `bokeh-1.4.0`

```
import bokeh
import bokeh.plotting

fig1 = bokeh.plotting.figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=200)
fig1.line([0,1],[0,1])
fig2 = bokeh.plotting.figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=200)
fig2.line([0,1],[1,0])
fig3 = bokeh.plotting.figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=200)
fig3.line([0,1,2],[1,0,1])
fig4 = bokeh.plotting.figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=200)
fig4.line([0,1,2],[0,1,0])
fig5 = bokeh.plotting.figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=200)
fig5.line([0,1,2],[0,0,1])

layout = bokeh.layouts.layout([
    [fig1,fig2],
    [fig3,fig4,fig5]

])
bokeh.io.show(layout)
```

the output looks as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the swifty replay! 
Your solution is my plan B.. Plan A is to make the figure sizes change dynamically with the window size.. Without plot_width and plot_height fig 1 and fig 2 will be equal size :/.. so, I want fig1 to use 66% of the first row, and fig2 33 %